# How to form Rally REST call API To get task details

Tags: api, rest, rally

I have a rest call of rally track the task details.

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/task/ObjectID

what is the object ID here to be used.

ANy lead would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you just make a call to the task query endpoint you can get details on multiple tasks at once:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/task

Use the fetch parameter to specify which fields you'd like returned.

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/task?fetch=FormattedID,ObjectID,Name